# Understanding unique_ptr get() function

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Will the `unique_ptr` `get()` stops the object from getting destroyed through some reference counting ?

Consider the below program :

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
int* getMemory(int N) {
    auto Up = std::make_unique<int[]>(N);
    return Up.get();
}


int main() {
    int* array = getMemory(10);
    for (int i=0;i<10;++i) {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    for(int i =0; i< 10; ++i) {
        std::cout<<array[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
```

I was expecting this program to crash, since the `unique_ptr` from `getMemory()` function should be destroyed after it's call, so the underlying memory to int* should be de-allocated. But surprisingly it is working :
https://godbolt.org/z/Gq1W7Gha8

Is my understanding of get wrong ?

Comment: Your understanding of `get` is fine. If there's anything you don't understand, it's that the code has undefined behavior, which means it may crash--but may also appear to work.

Comment: Turn on the compiler's address sanitizer and you're very likely to get the error you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks @chris, I could get the error that I expected using address sanitizer : https://godbolt.org/z/xnKf8ffWM . Can you please make this comment as answer ? I will accept it.

Comment: @DarshanBhat Is the AddressSanitizer verdict worth more than the answer to your question? Even the AddressSanitizer misses to find some violations so it helps to know what you're doing.

Comment: @TedLyngmo with due respect, whatever you told in the answer I already knew, but the compiler was still producing the right answer, so I got confused. The address sanitizer option gave the exact error I was looking. However, I have accepted your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will the unique_ptr get() stops the object from getting destroyed through some reference counting?

No, not at all. A `std::unqiue_ptr` is a simple wrapper around an owning pointer. No sharing. It's owning it. Calling `get()` gives the caller access to what the pointer is pointing at - but still, the ownership is held by the `unique_ptr`.

Perfect flaw:

```cpp
{
    auto a = std::make_unqiue<int>(0);
    delete a.get();
} // double free
```

---

Hiding the fact:

```
int* getMemory(int N) {
    auto Up = std::make_unique<int[]>(N);
    return Up.get();
} // The unique_ptr goes out of scope and frees the allocated memory

int* foo = getMemory(1);
*foo = 10; // undefined behavior - the memory is free'd
```